# Build a column based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a column that will be based off of another. The new column should reflect the values meeting certain criteria and put 0's where the values do not meet the criteria.

Example, a column called bank balance will have negative and positive values; the new column, overdraft, will have the negative values for the appropriate row and 0 where the balance is greater than 0.

```
 Bal  Ovr
 21   0
-34 -34
 45   0
-32 -32
```

The final result should look like that.

Comment: `df['Ovr'] = df['Bal'].clip(upper=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you can use `np.where` and do:

```
import numpy as np
df['Ovr'] = np.where(df['Bal'] <0,'df['Bal'],0)
```

which will create a column called `Ovr`, with 0's when `Bal` is +ve, and the same as `Bal` when `Bal` is -ve.

Answer (score 1):

```
df["over"] = df.Bal.apply(lambda x: 0 if x>0 else x)
```

Additional method to enrich your coding skills. However, it isn't needed for such easy tasks.